# Get multiple density plots of specifics columns for every data frame in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, ggplot2

I have 60 data frames which have the same columns names store in a list which i got by using this code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Visitor/Desktop/Unesco/")
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv)
```

A part of one of my csv files :

```
"","PRO","TRA","MEN","ENF","COU","TOI","REP","SOM","TEL","LOI"
"HAU","610","140","60","10","120","95","115","760","175","315"
"FAU","475","90","250","30","140","120","100","775","115","305"
"FNU","105","0","495","110","170","110","130","785","160","430"
"HMU","616","141","65","10","115","90","115","765","180","305"
"FMU","179","29","421","87","161","112","119","776","143","373"
```

I did a ggplot of the columns `PRO` and `TRA` of all my dataframes merge in one dataframe with this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

cols <-lapply(myfiles,function(x)select(x,PRO,TRA))
big_df2 <- do.call(rbind,cols)
df.m2 <- melt(big_df2)
ggplot(df.m2) + geom_freqpoly(aes(x = value,
+                                  y = ..density.., colour = variable))
```

I have this output:

[image]

But I want the same plot for all my data frames separately but i can't seem to find how to do that.

Maybe I can do something with this loop over my list :

```
for(i in 1:length(myfiles)){
    myfiles[[i]]$df_num <- i
}
```

Comment: There are many many many solution to this problem please show some research and code effort.

Comment: I added a lot of stuff^^.

Comment: When converting your list of dataframes to a single `big_df2` dataframe, add id for each dataframe (for example, read about rbindlist from data.table package) Then use facet in ggplot.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

# dummy data
set.seed(1)
df1 <- cars[sample(seq(nrow(cars)), 10), ]
df2 <- cars[sample(seq(nrow(cars)), 10), ]
df3 <- cars[sample(seq(nrow(cars)), 10), ]
mylist <- list(df1, df2, df3) #this is similar example of your "myfiles" 
mylist <- lapply(mylist, melt)

# merge them with an id column
df_merged <- bind_rows(mylist, .id = "df_id")

# Option 1: One plot as facets, 1 file 1 page
ggsave("option1.PDF",
       ggplot(df_merged, aes(value, col = variable)) + geom_freqpoly() +
         facet_grid(.~df_id)
       )

# Option 2: plot into files - output 3 PDF files
for(i in unique(df_merged$df_id)){
  filePDF <- paste0("option2_", i, ".PDF")
  myPlot <- df_merged %>%
    filter(df_id == i) %>%
    ggplot(aes(value, col = variable)) + geom_freqpoly()
  ggsave(filePDF, myPlot)
  }

# Option 3: plot into one file 3 pages
pdf("option3.PDF")
for(i in seq(length(df_merged))){
  plotDat <- df_merged %>%
    filter(df_id == i)
  myPlot <-  ggplot(plotDat, aes(value, col = variable)) + geom_freqpoly()
  print(myPlot)
  }
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thx but does it works if i want that each plot contain specifics columns of each dataframe?I can't test now.

Comment: Ah okay to do that i just have to make a list of subset data.frame with a lapply select()?

Comment: @JulienNguyen try it test it, let us know if you have problems.